# Bahri's Five Gaps in Mathematics paper

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Abbas Bahri wrote a paper called [Five Gaps in Mathematics](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwir46iEmv78AhWynVwKHQITD_EQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.math.rutgers.edu%2F%7Eabahri%2Fpapers%2Ffive%2520gaps.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2g_t-MYDNyrGqfsXry4Wl2). In discussions with differential geometers, I have found that many are aware of this paper, but few are aware of attempts to close the purported gaps. What are some references to papers or talks which address the concerns that Bahri raised in that paper (or equivalent concerns)?

Please note: I am *not* asking for your opinions of Bahri's concerns, or for your own concerns which might be similar to his.

Since there are only 5 purported gaps, and they are apparently, according to Bahri, related, it might be wise to collect these references in one place.

Comment: Rather than citing an omnibus paper, perhaps it would be better to ask specific questions about specific proofs?  i.e. pick one of the issues from Bahri's paper that you are concerned about, and ask a detailed question about that.  I think these sorts of big list questions don't often survive.

Comment: According to Google Scholar the Bahri paper is from 2015 and has only 2 quotations, by the author himself. This is not really what I would call a famous paper (although it might be famous outside the mathematics circle because of its presumptuous buzz-like title).

Comment: [Morgan and Tian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00699.pdf) published a correction to a part of their book dealing with the curve-shortening flow. They do not cite Bahri's paper, but he is mentioned in the article.

Comment: I find it quite curious that Bahri's paper does not contain references to the papers of Kleiner and Lott filling in details of Perelman's proof.

Comment: I was involved in the conversations between Bahri and Morgan-Tian on this topic and can confirm that the correction resolves the issue pointed out by Bahri (one of the error terms in Perelman's analysis was mistakenly omitted in the treatment in Morgan-Tian's book, but Perelman's sketch of the argument correctly incorporates this term).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Neither Kleiner-Lott nor Cao-Zhu's expositions covered this part of Perelman's work to any extent whatsoever, Morgan-Tian's was the only one to do so

Comment: @QuartoBendir: right, because they did not need to in order to prove geometrization.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Correct... I must have misunderstood your comment, sorry. I was only saying that Morgan-Tian (and Colding-Minicozzi) were the only works relevant for Bahri's comments

Comment: @QuartoBendir: This part of Bahri's paper comes under the heading "One of the concluding arguments for the proof of the three dimensional Poincare conjecture", making it appear that because one of the arguments (given by M&T) is faulty, this undermines the entire proof of PC3. I find this disingenuous. In contrast to PC3, the finite-time extinction result is a technical point that nobody outside of Riemannian Geometry would really care about.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't think that's a fair read, since he refers positively to Colding-Minicozzi's alternative argument for the same point

Comment: Anyway, to answer the original question: as Bahri says in a footnote, Kuwert's thesis resolves the graphical issue with Schoen and Schoen-Yau's proof of the positive mass theorem, and the three-dimensional case is in Colding-Minicozzi's book. Moreover (not mentioned by Bahri), a device of Lohkamp's reduces the positive mass theorem to the study of scalar curvature on connected sums with the torus, and I believe that both Lohkamp and Schoen-Yau's claimed proofs of the higher-dimensional positive mass theorem deal with this context, so that the graphical issue does not even come up.

Comment: anyone know the status of the monopole Floer homology proof? I haven't heard anyone talk about it at all...